# How do you get the width and height of a multi-dimensional array if i use it into Jagged Arrays?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multidimensional-array, jagged-arrays

I have an Array where i want to know each array length.

```
public int[][,] _EnemyPosition = new int[][,]
{
    new int[,]{ {0},{1},{2},{3},{4}},
    new int[,]{ {0,6},{1,7},{2,8},{3,9},{4,10}},
};

Debug.Log(_EnemyPosition.Length); // Output is 2
Debug.Log(_EnemyPosition[1].GetLength(0)); // Output is 5
```

But i am not able to get

```
 Debug.Log(_EnemyPosition[1][0].length);
```

Its throw me an error

```
error CS0022: Wrong number of indexes `1' inside [], expected `2'
```

i want to know how to get length of this array

```
_EnemyPosition[1][0].length
```

Comment: Since `_EnemyPosition` is `int[][,]` you can't call it with `_EnemyPosition[1][0]` - it has to be something like `_EnemyPosition[1][0,0]`. That's what the error is telling you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var length = _EnemyPosition[0].Length; //returns 5 (5·1)
var length = _EnemyPosition[1].Length; //returns 10 (5·2)
```

Is that what you want? Your requirement is far from clear:

> i want to know how to get length of this array: `_EnemyPosition[1][0].length`

That is not an array, `_EnemyPostion[1]` is a two dimensional array `[,]`. Consider the following analogue scenario:

```
int[,] myTwoDimensionalArray = ...
var whatever = myTwoDimensionalArray[0]; //not valid, array dimensiones don't match.
```

So, we have three options when it comes to the length you want returned:

1. `_EnemyPosition[1].Length` which returns the total length of the two dimensional array `10`.
2. `_EnemyPosition[1].GetLength(0)` which returns the length of the *first* dimension of the two dimensional array `5`
3. `_EnemyPosition[1].GetLength(1)` which returns the length of the *second* dimension of the two dimensional array `2`

And obviously the result of `2` times `3` is `1`. So, which one do you want?

Comment: Thank you so much sir Very Helpfull

Answer (score 3):

Let's disentangle the arrays: you have

```
 int[][,] _EnemyPosition
```

which is an *array* of *2d arrays*; so you can call

```
 _EnemyPosition.Length
```

which is number of 2d arrays in total; for each 2d array at `index` position you can call

```
 _EnemyPosition[index].GetLength(0)
 _EnemyPosition[index].GetLength(1)
```

which are the lengths of *each dimensions* (lines and columns) within `index`s 2d array. Please notice, that *jagged array* and *2d array* are different types; that's why you can't put

```
 // doesn't compile
 _EnemyPosition[1][0]
```

since `_EnemyPosition[1]` returns *2d array* which wants **2** indexes (something like `_EnemyPosition[1][0,1]`)

Comment: Thank You sir Its been very Helpful :)